# findById query is only returning _id field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this query:

```
  return Role.findById(_id, {lean: true}).exec().then(function (role: any) {

    if (!(role && role.key && role._id)) {
      log.error('role doc was missing the "key"/"_id" field =>', role);
      return;
    }

    caches.RolesCache[role.key] = role;
    caches.RolesCacheById[role._id] = role;
  });
```

I am getting this logged:

```
role doc was missing the "key"/"_id" field => { _id: 5ade466c1384a4deffac6b09 }
```

**Why would the findById function only return the _id field of the document? So weird. I swear this used to work fine. This is *not* happening for our other similar models, just this one.**

Note that I also tried:

`Role.findById(_id).lean().exec()`

`Role.findById(_id).exec()`

`Role.findOne({_id}).exec()`

and have the same issue.
when I got to the shell, I run:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.roles.find({_id:ObjectId("5ade466c1384a4deffac6b09")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ade466c1384a4deffac6b09"), "active" : true, "functionalGroup" : "IT", "defaultCategories" : [ "CATEGORY_GENERAL", "CATEGORY_NETWORK_LANDSCAPE", "CATEGORY_CALL_CENTER", "CATEGORY_TELECOMMUNICATIONS", "CATEGORY_VIDEO" ], "key" : "ROLE_XXX", "name" : "ROLE_XXX", "createdBy" : "alexamil", "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-23T20:47:40.413Z"), "updatedBy" : "alexamil", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-23T20:47:40.413Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

**anyone know what's going on?**

> I am on Mongoose version: 5.0.16, and Mongo version: 3.4.x

The schema definition for Role is:

```
'use strict';

import {Schema, Document, model, Model} from 'mongoose';
import {CDTBase, CDTBaseModel} from "../base-model";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const rolesSchema = new Schema(Object.assign({

  _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    auto: true
  },

  key: {
    // the canonical identifier (all uppercase, etc)
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  name: {
    // the display name
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  active: {
    // if we wish to deactivate this role, we would have to
    // change all users with this role to a different existing role
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },

  functionalGroup: {
    // functional group key
    type: String,
    // required: true,
    default: 'IT'
  },

  defaultCategories: {
    // default category keys
    type: [String],
    // required: true,
    default: []
  },

  persona: String,

}, CDTBase));


rolesSchema.index({name: 1}, {unique: true, background: false});
rolesSchema.index({key: 1}, {unique: true, background: false});

export interface CDTModel extends CDTBaseModel, Document{
  key: string,
  name: string,
  active: boolean,
  functionalGroup: string,
  defaultCategories: Array<string>,
  persona: string
}


export const cdtmodel = model<CDTModel>('Role', rolesSchema, 'roles');
```

base-model.ts just looks like:

```
export interface CDTBaseModel {
  createdAt?: Date,
  updatedAt?: Date,
  updatedBy?: string,
  createdBy?: string
}


export const CDTBase = {

  createdBy: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },

  updatedBy: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },

  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: false
  },

  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: false
  }

};
```

Comment: This would be a bit of a guessing game without knowing what the current schema is.

Comment: @JohnnyHK yep added it, our models haven't really changed, I figure it's more likely a change regarding mongo/mongoose versions than anything.

Comment: @JohnnyHK this is only happening for our Role model. I have similar code patterns for 3 other models, and all are working fine. Only Role is misbehaving, only responding with the _id field.

Comment: Then it's probably something outside of what you're showing, which looks ok, but there's a lot of code. I think we may need a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 1):

Change the query from

```
Role.findById(_id, {lean: true})
```

to

```
Role.findById(_id).lean()
```

According to [their docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById), the second argument is the projection, and it misses the `key`.

Comment: ughhh that is soooo gnarly, thanks, wouldn't have solved that one quickly

Comment: Hey @AlexanderMills , please enable debug mode, run the query at mongoose and see what it outputs.

Answer (score 0):

try with this please

```
Role.findById({_id},function (err,role) {

    if (err) throw err;
    if(!role){console.log("role not found")}
else{
    caches.RolesCache[role.key] = role;
    caches.RolesCacheById[role._id] = role;
}
  });
```

Comment: this shouldn't be any different than using the Promise interface, I update the question saying that Role is the only model we have that is misbehaving.

Comment: I dont use promise like you.I use like this:exec(function(role)...if i know what is **function(role:any)**,i can help you.